# divisibility of N from 1,2,3,...k

Tags: number-theory

Good day! I encountered this problem yesterday and I eventually answered the problem correctly.
The problem is this:If N is divisible by 1,2,3,. . . 13, then N must also be divisible by 14 and 15.

Using this same idea, what is the smallest integer  such that the following statement is true?

If N is divisible by 1,2,3,. . . M, then N must also be divisible by M + 1, M + 2, M + 3 and M + 4.
But I am wondering if there is a general rule/ proof/ algorithm for this? I used rough way to solve this one,,

Comment: You just need none of $M+1,M+2,M+3,M+4$ to all **not** be powers of primes. For example, $M=53.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think you are oversimplifying, in that, take M=7 for example  9 is a prime power but still divides into the product N potentially  because 3*6= 9*2. it really depends on what you call N and if you allow overlap etc.

Comment: If $N$ is divisible by $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ it is not necessarily divisible by $9$. @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: Rosa hasn't updated the question, but the idea is that for what $M$ is this true for all $N$? @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: okay I guess I'm just wanted more complex questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement is true if and only if each of $M+1,M+2,M+3,M+4$ is **not** a prime power.

I doubt there is a good way to find $M$ other than brute force. $M=53$ give $54,55,56,57$ without any prime powers, so that $M$ works, but I haven't found if it is the smallest.

More generally, for $M+1,M+2,\dots,M+k$, you'd need to know something about prime power gaps. I'm not sure what is known about that, but I'm assuming they are arbitrarily large.

For general $k$, I think you can use $M=(k+1)!^2+1$. Then $M+1,M+2,\dots,M+k$ are not prime powers, but this $M$ is not the smallest such $M$ by far.

A smaller $M$ for a general $k$ is:

$$M=1+\prod_{p\leq k+1} p^{1+\lfloor \log_p (k+1)\rfloor}$$

This gives $M=13$ for $k=2$ and $M=1+8\cdot 9=73$ for $k=3$.

Comment: At first my answer is M = 23, but it happens that M + 4 = 27 = 3^3 which does not contain a factor from any of the previous number..so my answer is M = 32. sir..

Comment: But I assume that your correct since prime gaps do not assume any pattern in the whole real number system.

Comment: Yes, $M=32$ works.

Comment: In fact $58=2\cdot 29$ so $M=53$ gives a sequence of five numbers.

Comment: This answer is incomplete and is not an answer

Comment: And yet, the asker selected this as a correct answer. @Raffaele

Comment: Sir @Thomas Andrews I wonder how did you formulate the value of M in terms of logarithms... I verify it and it holds true... what about p? what it means? prime? Sir if it does not bother you I would like to see your derivation on the formula tnx a lot :) It's interesting to know.

Comment: @rosa Yes, the product is over primes $p$ such that $p\geq k+1$. The exponent $1+\lfloor\log_p(k+1)\rfloor$ is just the smallest exponent $r$ such that $p^r>k+1$.

Comment: I really wish to see how you generate your formula because I cannot trace how you came up to such formula.. especially the exponent part with base p..

Comment: If $M$ is defined as above then $M+j$ is divisible by $j+1$ for $j=1,2,\dots k$. So for $M+j$ to be a prime power, you need $j+1$ to be a prime power, $p^{\ell}$. But $M\equiv 0\pmod{p^{\ell+1}}$ by the definition of $M$, so $M+j\equiv p^{\ell}\pmod{p^{\ell+1}}$ and hence $M+j$ is not a power of $p$. @rosa

Comment: why product..? and  your comment about $$M = (k + 1)!^2 + 1$$ how did you came up with such findings? sorry for my lackings... :(

Comment: I was working analogously to the proof that there are arbitrarily large prime gaps, using the fact that $(k+1)!+i$ is not prime for $i=2,3,\dots,k+1$. For my argument, you need that $M+2,M+3,\dots,M+k+1$ to not be powers of primes.

Comment: I see... :) sir thank you very much for your wisdom and patience! I'll work - out to understand the rest of your formula :) A little bit confuse but still I'll try my best :) tnx a lot sir! :)

Comment: SIr, I just want to verify your claim that if M is defined as aboved M + j is divisible by j + 1 for j = 1,2,3,..., k.

I let M = 32, (since this works up to M + 4) but as i verify your claim I turned into this, if j = 1, and j + 1 = 2,,, M + j = 32 + 1 = 33,,,but 2 does not divided 33. Please correct my thinking...

Comment: But the $M$ above is not of the product form. My product doesn't give the best value $M$, my product just gives *a* value $M$. $M=32$ won't have the property that $M+i$ is divisible by $i+1$. I specifically defined my value to have that property. So for $k=4$ it gives $M=1801$ and $M+i$ is divisible by $i+1$ and for $i=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: There is likely no fast way to find the smallest such $M$ for any $k$, but my product formula is a proof that there is such an $M$ for each $k$. The product formula is designed to make it relatively easy to see that $M+i$ cannot be a prime power for $i=1,2,\dots,k$.

Comment: I see sir,,, sorry for not sticking to your definition, my bad. I verify your formula using k = 1, 2,3,4 . . .11 I found out that k = 4 and k = 5 has the same M and k = 8 to 15 has the same M,, also the formula failed at k = 12 for M = 529 201 and M + 12 = 529 213 which is a prime.

Comment: With $k=12,$ you should get $M=2^{4}3^35^27^211^313^2+1=10821610801$. You forgot $11^2$ and $13^2$.

Comment: Really, you should just try iter without a computer. If $M=2^{4}3^35^27^211^313^2+1$, then $M+1\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ so it can't be a prime power. $M+2\equiv 3\pmod{3^3}$, so $M+2$ is divisible by $3$ but not a power of $3$. $M+3\equiv 4\pmod{8}$, $M+4\equiv 5\pmod{25}$, etc.

Comment: My bad... haixt! Tnx for the effort and patience sir! This will be the last,,, I hope :) tnx a lot :)

Answer (score -2):

**hint**

If one of the four numbers $M+1, M+2, M+3 , M+4$ is prime, the statement is not true.

the primes are
$2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37... $

So, the possible values of $M $ are

$$23,31,32,47,53$$
you check them one by one until 53 which works.

Comment: It's asking to find the smallest number $M$ such that this is true.

Comment: It's not my question, but note that the question says "Using this same idea, what is the smallest integer such that the following statement is true?"

Comment: Sorry, @Daminark, misattributed.

Comment: If $N$ is divisible by $2,3,4,\dots,23$, it is not divisible by $25$. $5\mid 20$ and $10\mid 20$, but $25\not\mid 20$.

Answer (score -2):

$144\,403\,552\,893\,600=2^5\times 3^3\times 5^2\times 7\times 11\times 13\times 17\times 19\times 23\times 29\times 31$

Is divisible by $2,\;3,\;\ldots,31$ and by $32,\;33,\;35,\;36$ and is the smallest number with such a property

It is a product of primorials, BTW...

Comment: The question is not to find the smallest $N$. It is to find $M$ such that it is true for all $N$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Please go and read again the OP question "[...]what is the smallest integer such that the following statement is true?

If N is divisible by 1,2,3,. . . M, then N must also be divisible by M + 1, M + 2, M + 3 and M + 4. [...]"

Comment: Where does OP say smallest integer $N$? The "If $N$..." part of the sentence would indicate that this is not the integer that the OP is looking for, because "IF X then Y" is true if $X$ is false, so to find the smallest $N$, you could choose $N=1$ and $M=4$ and it would be true. The question is asking about the smallest $M$, not the smallest $N$.